How to stop a rig from deforming the model?
I've been trying to animate something, so I imported a model from Roblox Studio and a Roblox Rig I found online to Blender and parented the two. For some reason, when I move the rig, the model gets deformed as if it were stuck on something. How can I stop this from happening?
What the rig is supposed to do 
What the rig is doing to the model 
Terribly sorry if I'm not able to describe much more clearly than that, I just started blender. I'll add the .blend file if anyone wants to take a crack at it; it'd be much appreciated

Rig used, if it helps: https://softgb.gumroad.com/l/robloxstarterrigs

it would be helpful, if you could add some informations what the armatures should do and how it should look like.

I updated the question with gifs in hopes to make it a little clearer on what the rigs are supposed to be doing and look like normally
